# Proof verification : Is my modified moduli problem still representable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, schemes, moduli-space

I came across a moduli problem which looks very similar to another one appearing in a little lemma by Rapoport and Zink. I tried to prove that mine is also representable, but as a newbie in this topic I would appreciate some proof verification. Could somebody please confirm if what I wrote is correct ?

---

Lemma 2.10 in Rapoport and Zink's book "Period spaces for $p$-divisible groups" reads the following

> Let $S$ be any scheme and let $\alpha : \mathcal M \to \mathcal L$ be a morphism of $\mathcal O_S$-modules, with $\mathcal L$ being finite and locally free. Let $F$ denote the functor from the category of $S$-schemes to that of sets, sending an $S$-scheme $T$ to the set
> $$F(T):= \{\phi \in \mathrm{Hom}(T,S) \,|\, \phi^*\alpha = 0\}$$
> The functor $F$ is representable by a closed subscheme of $S$.

Here, $\phi^*\alpha$ denotes the morphism $\mathcal M_T \to \mathcal L_T$ induced by base change to $T$.
The proof is not that difficult. Because we have an isomorphism
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal M,\mathcal L) \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal M \otimes \mathcal L ^{*},\mathcal O_S)$$
where $\mathcal L^{*} := \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal L,\mathcal O_S)$, the morphism $\alpha$ corresponds to some $\tilde{\alpha}:  \mathcal M \otimes \mathcal L ^{*} \to \mathcal O_S$. The image of $\tilde{\alpha}$ is a sheaf of ideals in $\mathcal O_S$, which defines the desired closed subscheme.

---

I am interested in the following similar moduli problem.

Let $R$ be a DVR with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Let $S$ be any scheme over $R$, and denote by $\overline S$ its special fiber, that is the fiber over $\mathfrak m$. It is a closed subscheme of $S$, defined over the field $R/\mathfrak m$.
Let $\overline{\alpha}:\overline{\mathcal M} \to \overline{\mathcal L}$ be a morphism of $\mathcal O_{\overline S}$-modules, with $\overline{\mathcal L}$ being finite and locally free. Let $F$ denote the functor from the category of $S$-schemes to that of sets, sending an $S$-scheme $T$ to the set
$$F(T):= \{\phi \in \mathrm{Hom}(T,S) \,|\, \overline{\phi}^*\alpha = 0\}$$
Here, $\overline{\phi}$ is the induced morphism $\overline T \to \overline S$ on the special fibers (the structure morphism $T\to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ being given by means of $\phi$).

**Is $F$ representable by a closed subscheme of $S$ ?**

I believe the answer to be affirmative, for a simple reason : a composition of closed immersions is again a closed immersion.
To be more precise, let $\overline F$ denote the same functor as in Rapoport and Zink's lemma, but over $\overline S$. It is represented by a closed subscheme of $\overline S$. Now, we may see it as a closed subscheme of $S$ as a whole, by composition of closed immersions. This should be our desired closed subscheme.

Is everything ok with my statement and justification ?

Comment: The answer is no, I think. It is like asking whether there is a closed subscheme of the affine line over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ consisting of points whose reduction modulo $p$ is the origin. This kind of object does exist, but it is a kind of formal scheme or rigid analytic variety.

Comment: Counterexample: Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}_p, S=\operatorname{Spec} R$ and $\overline{\alpha}$ the identity map on $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{S}}$. Then $\overline{\phi}^{\ast} \alpha$ is the zero map if and only if $\overline{\phi}^{\ast} \mathcal{O}_S$ is the zero module. This happens if and only if the basechange $T \otimes_{S} \overline{S}$ is the zero scheme, which happens if and only if $p$ is invertible on $T$ (or if $T$ is the zero scheme). It will be representable (which is an accident as far as I'm concerned), but by the open subscheme $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}_p \subset S$

Comment: Instead you might be able to try to prove that your functor, restricted to the category of $R$-schemes where $\pi$ (a uniformiser of $R$) is locally nilpotent, is representable by a closed formal subscheme of the completion $\hat{S}$ of $S$ in $\overline{S}$. If $X \subset \overline{S}$ is the functor representing the Rapoport-Zink moduli space, then it might be true that this functor is representable by the completion of $S$ in $X$ [but this is merely speculation on my part].

Comment: Thank you very much @PolvanHoften for your comments. I agree with you : in fact, while thinking back again on the matter after writing my post, I realized that my argument fails as you pointed out. My argument fails to take the generic fiber into account, I suppose. Your suggestion of trying to consider formal schemes, and the category of schemes where the uniformizer is locally nilpotent, sounds convincing and may very well correspond to what I am looking in my study. Thanks a lot !